# In CQ5/AEM how does components' Item Load Path work behind the scene?

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

In CQ5, the Item Load Path field allow an author to provide a url from which it loads the options available in a dropdown list/checkbox group etc. But how does it actually work?

***EDIT: I'm using version 5.6.1 in case that is relevant***

Here is what I do know:

1) I know that component dialogs in CQ5 stores its content under:

```
/content/page/jcr:content/<component node>
```

In this case, it's stored in a property called './optionLoadPath':

[image]

2) I know that Inside any component (for example, the checkbox components), the list of values to be displayed is loaded into a List of Strings via:

***EDIT 2: @awadheshv just pointed out that the list of values to be displayed is actually loaded using FormsHelper.getOptions(). If that's the case, what is getValueAsList doing?***

```
final List<String> values = FormsHelper.getValuesAsList(slingRequest, resource);
```

before being displayed using a forloop:

```
for (String v : displayValues.keySet()) {
    final String t = displayValues.get(v);
    final String currentId = id + "-" + i;

%><div class="form_row"><%
    LayoutHelper.printTitle(currentId, t, false, true, out);
    %><div class="form_rightcol"><%

            String checked = "";
            if (values.contains(v)) {
                checked = " checked=\"checked\"";
            }
        %><input class="<%= FormsHelper.getCss(properties, "form_field form_field_checkbox") %>" type="checkbox"
                 id="<%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(currentId) %>" name="<c:out value="<%= name %>"/>"
                 value="<c:out value="<%= v %>"/>" <%= checked %> />&nbsp;<c:out value="<%= t %>" />
    </div>
</div><%

    i++;
}
```

3) I also know that FormsHelper.getValuesAsList just calls FormsHelper.getValues and just converts the returned array into a list.

```
public static List<String> getValuesAsList(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final Resource elementResource) {
    final String[] values = getValues(request, elementResource);
    if ( values == null ) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return Arrays.asList(values);
}
```

But I don't understand how everything comes together. At what point/how is the list of items in optionLoadPath passed to FormsHelper?

Furthermore, if I want to load in the values by default, how would I go about doing that? For example, say if there is a list of countries I want to load into the componenet. I still want to give user the ability to change the URL to a different list of countries if they want, but I want to load in a default list as soon as the component is dropped into the page. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think loadOptions are fetched via `getValues`. FormsHelper class has a separate method `getOptions` which fetches optionsLoadPath property from jcr; implemented as follows-

```
public static Map<String, String> getOptions(SlingHttpServletRequest request, Resource elementResource)
  {
    ValueMap properties = ResourceUtil.getValueMap(elementResource);

    String[] options = null;
    String loadPath = (String)properties.get("optionsLoadPath", "");
    if (loadPath.length() > 0)
    {
      Resource rsrc = request.getResourceResolver().getResource(loadPath);
      if (rsrc != null) {
        options = (String[])rsrc.adaptTo([Ljava.lang.String.class);
      }
    }

    if (options == null) {
      options = (String[])properties.get("options", [Ljava.lang.String.class);
    }

    if (options == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Map splitValues = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
      String value = options[i].trim();
      if (value.length() > 0) {
        boolean endLoop = true;
        int pos = -1;
        int start = 0;
        do {
          pos = value.indexOf(61, start);

          if ((pos > 0) && (value.charAt(pos - 1) == '\\')) {
            start = pos + 1;
            endLoop = false;
          } else {
            endLoop = true; }
        }
        while (!(endLoop));
        String t;
        if (pos == -1) {
          String v = value;
          t = value;
        } else {
          v = value.substring(0, pos);
          t = value.substring(pos + 1);
        }
        String v = v.replace("\\=", "=");
        String t = t.replace("\\=", "=");
        splitValues.put(v, t);
      } else {
        splitValues.put("", "");
      }
    }
    if (splitValues.size() == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return splitValues;
  }
```

component code would call getOptions explicitly. e.g.-

```
 Map<String, String> displayValues = FormsHelper.getOptions(slingRequest, resource);
```

to you second point - you can put the default values in `options` property.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Just to clarify, when you say "you can put the default values in options property" which options property of which node do you mean? and how would you go about loading in the default options?

Comment: It should be on the same node where you have `optionsLoadPath`. and you don't need to write additional code to load it. if you look at the getOptions() code above it uses `options` as a fallback when `optionsLoadPath` returns null.